# Time shifted testing in JBOSS

Tags: java, time, jboss

I am working on an enterprise application running in JBOSS application server. The application records product subscriptions and creates transactions once a month.

I want to develop an automated test case in which it makes a subscription, shifts the date by 10 months and creates transactions(10 transactions need to be created).

Is there any way to shift the date in JBOSS application server using Java?

Comment: Something like `Calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -10)`?

Comment: You mean changing the system time where the Jboss instance is running?

Comment: not really. in theory any place in your code that calls System.currentTimeMillis() is a problem. you need to move all time/date related calls to a single EJB and then mock/replace it.

Comment: Here is an idea of how to mock the `System` class to return a fake time during testing: http://virgo47.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/changing-system-time-in-java/

Comment: Mocking the system class just worked. But I have found another problem. This approach change the time of the JVM. Is there anyway to restrict it a particular class loader of the JVM ?. Because I just want to change the time in my application but not the JBOSS itself.